# Ember.js / Rails Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I'm working on a basic Ember / Rails app that has a bunch of nested relationships, for example:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks
end
```

When I hit my Releases endpoint, I'm getting some lovely JSON like this:

```
{
  releases: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Release Name",
    artist: "Artist Name",
    tracks: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Track 1",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Track 2",
    }]
  }]
}
```

I've read almost everything I can find on the web about this. How do I map the "Track" model to Ember, so I can display a release with its tracks at the same time?

`DS.hasMany`?  `asyc:true`?  `embedded:true`?  None of this works for me.

Versions:

- Ember: 1.4.0-beta.1+canary.011b67b8
- Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.d9ce2a53
- Handlebars: 1.1.1
- jQuery: 1.10.2

Comment: which adapter are you using?

Comment: I'm on DS.ActiveModelAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me using [Active Model Serializer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast) and `DS.RESTAdapter`

Rails User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

Rails User Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :photos, embed: :ids, key: "photos", include: true
end
```

(The magic bit the arguments for has_many. That means they get added them as a second array rather than an embedded array, it also sets the title for the association to be `photos` which is what Ember requires by default)

This makes Rails return JSON that looks like:

```
{
  user: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Joe Bloggs",
    photos: [1,2]
  },
  photos: [
    {
      id: 1,
      imageSrc: "/photo1.jpg"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      imageSrc: "/photo2.jpg"
    }
  ],
}
```

Then in Ember I define the user model like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  photos: DS.hasMany('photo'),
  name: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Finally I define a route that loads the user model:

```
App.UserShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks Laurie - I actually figured this out a couple days ago but haven't had the time to update my post! 

"embed: :ids, key: "photos", include: true" is the kicker!!